# Why does Paragus look younger in DBZ Legendary SSJ compared to DBS Broly

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Like if you watched the old Broly (the first one) He looked way younger, and in the DBS version he looks very old. So does that mean Goku, Vegeta, Gohan, Piccolo and Trunks minds where whipped clean?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.polygon.com/2018/7/10/17550980/broly-canon-dragon-ball-super-z-movie-legendary-super-saiyan

> Because of his limited appearances, fans have debated if Broly can be considered part of the larger Dragon Ball canon for years. But in a note on the Dragon Ball Super: Broly website, series creator Akira Toriyama said he worked to fit Broly into the Dragon Ball universe.

Hopefully that links confirms that Broly is canon now. The movie basically retcons Broly's origin. That's why his father looks older and different than in the DBZ Movie.

Comment: The only thing that confuses me. then why come out with the other 3 movies, The legendary super saiyan, bio Broly and Broly second coming. its like seeing Hitler in the Gogeta move (the first appearance of Gogeta in a movie)

Comment: Broly - Legendary Super Saiyan came out in 1993. That's over 20 years between that and DBS: Broly. Its safe to say that there's a newer generation of fans. And it might not be viable for fans to go back and watch the entire DBZ series and be confused when the story doesn't line up with the movies. I think only a handful of movies are actually canon to the series. If that makes sense? Hopefully?

Comment: Thanks, Im not that confused that much anymore, But like I said the movies are weird with "CANNON" And "NOT CANNON"

Comment: Agreed. I do respect the fact that they're trying to bring back old favorites to try and refresh the series again.

Answer (score 0):

The *Paragus* from the old Broly movie is not canon while the *Paragus* from Dragon Ball Super Broly is. They are 2 separate characters and you shouldn't establish any form of relations between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think Toei wanted to distinguish between the canon and noncanon versions of Paragus so fans don't get confused when making fanart. As Gary said, you really shouldn't think of these two characters as existing in a uniform timeline and universe as one is canon and the other is noncanon to Dragon Ball.